# Unable to tally help file with source (example: os module)

Tags: python, class

I am learning how to read python docs and less reliant on the internet examples. Not easy, but I will try.

In python cli, i

> import os

When I `help(os)`, the following output was returned

> ```
> CLASSES
> builtins.Exception(builtins.BaseException)
> builtins.OSError
> builtins.object
>     nt.DirEntry
> builtins.tuple(builtins.object)
>     nt.times_result
>     nt.uname_result
>     stat_result
>     statvfs_result
>     terminal_size
>
> class DirEntry(builtins.object)
>  |  Methods defined here:
> ```

I cannot find the `class DirEntry` in the os.py source file. Can someone enlighten me why `help(os)` returns with DirEntry

Comment: Why just dont read the official docs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, @Avión
It's comfortable to read (and copy) other programmers' code but that reduces thinking
I'm trying to learn how I can rely on offline manpage/help to understand and program better.
If I can understand how to make use of this help page, it will benefit me when learning other modules too.

Comment: It's not a page of *others programmers code* it's the *official* docs. The good way is to read the official docs via website, not using the `help()` command.

Comment: Good point @Avión, guess I'm just try too hard not to depend on the internet. I've downloaded a copy of docs.python.org for that.

Comment: That's the way you should learn Python, using the official docs. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you print the representation of `os.DirEntry`, and as you can see in the help, it is the object `nt.DirEntry` (Because you are on a windows system):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.DirEntry
<class 'nt.DirEntry'>
>>> os.DirEntry.__module__
'nt'
>>> help(os.DirEntry)
Help on class DirEntry in module nt:

class DirEntry(builtins.object)
...
>>> import nt
>>> nt.DirEntry is os.DirEntry
True
```

The place where `DirEntry` is imported from `nt` in the `os` module is here:

```
elif 'nt' in _names:
    name = 'nt'
    linesep = '\r\n'
    from nt import *
```

The `from nt import *` imports (mostly) everything from the `nt` module, which is where `DirEntry` is added to the `os` module.

Comment: Thanks @Artyer. This certainly helps me to understand the origins of this part in help(os)